# Why requests.post() not working on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, api, flask, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I am working on Jupyter Notebook.

My flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import json
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/details', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
        data = request.form
        return jsonify(data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It's working fine but whenever I am running requests.post() code it's getting stuck  (In[*])

The code is:

```
import requests
payload = {'A': 'B','C': 'D'}
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/details',data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Does it work if you run the flask app in the command line / terminal? Jupyter is not really that suitable for developing web applications. I'd recommend PyCharm or VS Code.

Comment: Yeah, it's working well on Pycharm. But I need to run it on Jupyter.

Comment: By default the port for Jupyter should by 8888 instead of 5000. Source: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html